# How can i make this list possible?

Tags: android, android-intent, messaging

How can I make this list

[image: This is a image to add smiley when messaging-core feature]

appear when I click on options for my edit text?
Or else do I have an option for creating this list with code or as xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this Code for Adding Smiley with Image of particular Image :

[Smiley in List View](http://dipakkeshariyainandroid.blogspot.com/2011/08/how-to-add-smileyemojis-in-edittext.html)